# Oracle strong ref cursor with dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

I'm using Oracle 10g. I have a query in a stored procedure that selects entire rows from a table. Currently it returns a strongly typed ref cursor (tablename%rowtype). Now I have to add some dynamic WHERE clauses to this query, but dynamic SQL doesn't support a strong ref cursor. [It has been asked on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783461/why-cant-we-use-strong-ref-cursor-with-dynamic-sql-statement). My question is: is there a workaround? Use some kind of wrapper or conversion or DBMS magic to convert from the weak cursor to the strong cursor? I can guarantee that the results match the table rowtype.

Comment: Are you certain that you need dynamic SQL to add the predicates?  Are you sure you can't have a static query with predicates like `where (parameter = 'A' and (something))` that would only evaluate the `something` predicate if `parameter` is `A`?

Comment: We have wasted many hours with this. We just couldn't make Oracle use indexes if the indexed where clauses are conditional like that.

Comment: Do you need a ref cursor? If you can do bulk collect into a PL/SQL table as in @DieterDHoker's answer, could you iterate over that rather than iterate over your strong ref cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to achieve your underlying goal, but if you really want values from dynamic SQL into a strongly typed refcursor I guess you could do something like this:

```
create table TESTTABLE(TESTID number not null);
create global temporary table TEMPTESTTABEL(TESTID number not null);

create or replace procedure testprocedure is 
  type testtablerefcursor is ref cursor return TESTTABLE%rowtype;
  type testtabletable is table of TESTTABLE%rowtype;
  mycursor testtablerefcursor;
  mysyscursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  mytesttable testtabletable;
begin
  open mysyscursor for 'select * from TESTTABLE';
  fetch mysyscursor bulk collect into mytesttable;
  close mysyscursor;
  forall i in mytesttable.first..mytesttable.last
   insert into TEMPTESTTABEL values mytesttable(i);
  open mycursor for select testid from TEMPTESTTABEL;
end;
/
```